# getopt does not parse optional arguments to parameters

Tags: c, arguments, getopt, getopt-long, optional-arguments

In C, getopt_long does not parse the optional arguments to command line parameters parameters.

When I run the program, the optional argument is not recognized like the example run below.

```
$ ./respond --praise John
Kudos to John
$ ./respond --blame John
You suck !
$ ./respond --blame
You suck !
```

Here is the test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int getopt_ret, option_index;
    static struct option long_options[] = {
               {"praise",  required_argument, 0, 'p'},
               {"blame",  optional_argument, 0, 'b'},
               {0, 0, 0, 0}       };
    while (1) {
        getopt_ret = getopt_long( argc, argv, "p:b::",
                                  long_options,  &option_index);
        if (getopt_ret == -1) break;

        switch(getopt_ret)
        {
            case 0: break;
            case 'p':
                printf("Kudos to %s\n", optarg); break;
            case 'b':
                printf("You suck ");
                if (optarg)
                    printf (", %s!\n", optarg);
                else
                    printf ("!\n", optarg);
                break;
            case '?':
                printf("Unknown option\n"); break;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm documenting this here with the answer, so other people does not need to bang their head against the wall.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Although not mentioned in glibc documentation or getopt man page, optional arguments to long style command line parameters require 'equals sign' (=). Space separating the optional argument from the parameter does not work.

An example run with the test code:

> ```
> $ ./respond --praise John
> Kudos to John
> $ ./respond --praise=John
> Kudos to John
> $ ./respond --blame John
> You suck !
> $ ./respond --blame=John
> You suck , John!
> ```

Comment: Note that Perl's Getopt::Long module does NOT have the same requirement. Boost.Program_options does.

Comment: Wow, this sucks. I ran into the same problem with regular getopt() and when using an optstring "a::", optarg would only be set if you have ZERO space between the option and the argument such as '-afoo'

Comment: At least for my short options like `-a` or `-a=300`, I needed to add an `if (optarg[0] == '=') {memmove(optarg, optarg+1, strlen(optarg));}` to strip away the `=`. Otherwise, I would always have had `=300` in `optarg`. Or I would have needed to call it like this: `-a300` - which is quite ugly I think. Thanks for your answer anyway, it helped me a lot!

Comment: In this case it's better not to use optional arguments. Is this a bug or a feature? Now I have an urge to `./respond --blame=glibc`.

Comment: I wanted to downvote but then realized that your answer is great; it's just the behaviour I want to downvote. Thanks!

Comment: But why? It's explicitly encouraged by sites founder Jeff Atwood. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: To the people complaining about this _feature_: if an option has an optional argument, there is no way to distinguish between an option to that argument, and an extra argument that comes after options.

Comment: Accidentally sent my comment before I'd finished writing it..

Say I have a program with this usage:
`program [--option [<arg>]] [<argument>]`

If you run `program --option something`, it is ambiguous whether `something` is the `<arg>` of `--option`, or the `<argument>` of the program. The only way to remove the ambiguity is to force `<arg>` to be attached to `--option`.

The developers of glibc have given us sane defaults here instead of undefined behaviour... Developers using getopt are free to create their own logic if they want to handle it in a different way that works for them.

Answer (score 18):

The man page certainly doesn't document it very well, but the source code helps a little.

Briefly: you're supposed to do something like the following (though this may be a little over-pedantic):

```
if(   !optarg
   && optind < argc // make sure optind is valid
   && NULL != argv[optind] // make sure it's not a null string
   && '\0' != argv[optind][0] // ... or an empty string
   && '-' != argv[optind][0] // ... or another option
  ) {
  // update optind so the next getopt_long invocation skips argv[optind]
  my_optarg = argv[optind++];
}
/* ... */
```

> From among the comments preceding _getopt_internal:
>
> ...
>
> If `getopt` finds another option character, it returns that character,
>   **updating `optind`** and `nextchar` so that the next call to `getopt` can
>   resume the scan with the following option character or ARGV-element.
>
> If there are no more option characters, `getopt` returns -1.
>   Then `optind` is the index in ARGV of the first ARGV-element
>   that is not an option.  (The ARGV-elements have been permuted
>   so that those that are not options now come last.) `<-- a note from me:
>   if the 3rd argument to getopt_long starts with a dash, argv will not
>   be permuted`
>
> ...
>
> If a char in OPTSTRING is followed by a colon, that means it wants an arg,
>   so the following text in the same ARGV-element, or the text of the following
>   ARGV-element, is returned in `optarg`.  Two colons mean an option that
>   wants an optional arg; if there is text in the current ARGV-element,
>   it is returned in `optarg`, **otherwise `optarg` is set to zero**.
>
> ...

... though you have to do some reading between the lines.  The following does what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  int getopt_ret;
  int option_index;
  static struct option long_options[] = {
      {"praise",  required_argument, 0, 'p'}
    , {"blame",  optional_argument, 0, 'b'}
    , {0, 0, 0, 0}
  };

  while( -1 != ( getopt_ret = getopt_long(  argc
                                          , argv
                                          , "p:b::"
                                          , long_options
                                          , &option_index) ) ) {
    const char *tmp_optarg = optarg;
    switch( getopt_ret ) {
      case 0: break;
      case 1:
        // handle non-option arguments here if you put a `-`
        // at the beginning of getopt_long's 3rd argument
        break;
      case 'p':
        printf("Kudos to %s\n", optarg); break;
      case 'b':
        if(   !optarg
           && NULL != argv[optind]
           && '-' != argv[optind][0] ) {
          // This is what makes it work; if `optarg` isn't set
          // and argv[optind] doesn't look like another option,
          // then assume it's our parameter and overtly modify optind
          // to compensate.
          //
          // I'm not terribly fond of how this is done in the getopt
          // API, but if you look at the man page it documents the
          // existence of `optarg`, `optind`, etc, and they're
          // not marked const -- implying they expect and intend you
          // to modify them if needed.
          tmp_optarg = argv[optind++];
        }
        printf( "You suck" );
        if (tmp_optarg) {
          printf (", %s!\n", tmp_optarg);
        } else {
          printf ("!\n");
        }
        break;
      case '?':
        printf("Unknown option\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf( "Unknown: getopt_ret == %d\n", getopt_ret );
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked really well, thanks. Not sure where you got optindex from; it's called (extern int) optind for me.

Comment: There is an error in the second code example, it should be `optind` instead of `optindex`.

Comment: Looks like the code should maintain optindex. Otherwise, it will point to 0 always. we need to advance optindex for every option.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this issue myself. I arrived at a similar solution to the one Brian Vandenberg and Haystack suggested. But to improve readability and avoid code duplication, you can wrap it all up in a macro like below:

```
#define OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT_IS_PRESENT \
    ((optarg == NULL && optind < argc && argv[optind][0] != '-') \
     ? (bool) (optarg = argv[optind++]) \
     : (optarg != NULL))
```

The macro can be used like this:

```
case 'o': // option with optional argument
    if (OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT_IS_PRESENT)
    {
        // Handle is present
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle is not present
    }
    break;
```

If you are interested, you can read more about how this solution works in a blog post I wrote:
https://cfengine.com/blog/2021/optional-arguments-with-getopt-long/

This solution is tested and is – at the time of this writing – currently used in CFEngine.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem and came here. Then I realised this .
You don't have much of a use case of "optional_argument" . If an option is required you check from program logic, if an option is optional then you need not do anything because at getopt level all options are optional , they are not mandatory, so there is no use case of "optional_argument". Hope this helps.

ps: for the above example i think the correct options are 
--praise --praise-name "name" --blame --blame-name "name"

Comment: *You don't have much of a use case of "optional_argument"* -- Oh, but we do. Imagine that we have `$ whip --spank user5081924` and `$ whip --spank`. The first spanks a specific user, the second spanks the caller. Without the optional argument you'd be forced to either only spank yourself or only spank others. (Could have a `--spank-self` and `--spank-other` I suppose, but why complicate.)