# cmdargs value arguments without equals sign

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, haskell-cmdargs

I use [`cmdargs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.7/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html) to write CLI parsers for my Haskell programs.

Let's assume this program, derived directly from their example:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import System.Console.CmdArgs.Implicit

data Sample = Sample {hello :: String} deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

sample = Sample{hello = def &= help "World argument" &= opt "world"}
         &= summary "Sample v1"

main = print =<< cmdArgs sample
```

If this program is called `cmdtest.hs`, I can execute

```bash
$ runghc cmdtest.hs --hello=world
Sample {hello = "world"}
```

However, if I leave off the equals sign (like in the `-o` option in `gcc -o foo foobar.c`), cmdargs tries to recognize `world` as a positional argument

```bash
$ runghc cmdtest.hs --hello world
Unhandled argument, none expected: world
```

Is there any option / annotation I can set to allow this syntax in cmdargs?

**Update:** Using the short option exposes the same problem:

```bash
$ runghc cmdtest.hs -h world
Unhandled argument, none expected: world
```

**Update 2:** The [`FlagInfo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.9.5/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-Explicit.html#t%3aFlagInfo) `data` in the cmdargs `Explicit` module seems to suggest it is somehow possible, at least if using `Explicit` instead of `Implicit`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're using `opt` which makes the value of `--hello` optional. So `--hello world` is taken to mean `--hello` without a value, followed by `world` as a positional parameter. This is of course a design choice in `cmdargs`, but I think it's a reasonable one, and it matches the behaviour of most other programs. Take out the `opt` and see if it works the way you want.

Comment: Apparently, the GNU C function getopt_long behaves the same way. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052746/getopt-does-not-parse-optional-arguments-to-parameters), for example.

Comment: I found it a bit surprising. See https://github.com/ndmitchell/cmdargs/issues/2 and linked discussion.