# Parsing command line with getopt_long()

Tags: c++, command-line

I cant seem to obtain multiple command line arguments using getopt_long().  my code segfaults after it prints 1.  I have another way to parse command line but it s killing me that this isnt working.  Its so simple.  Any ideas? thanks

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int val;
std::string clcf;
int futures (0), blocks(0);


static struct option long_options[] =
{
    { "config"          , required_argument     , 0     , 'c' },
    { "sstest"            , optional_argument     , 0     , 's' },
    { "btest"          , optional_argument     , 0     , 'b' },
  //{ "ssfspreads"      , optional_argument     , 0     , 'S' },
  //{ "blockspreads"    , optional_argument     , 0     , 'B' },
    { 0                 , 0                     , 0     ,  0  }
};

while ((val = getopt_long (argc, argv, GETARGLIST.c_str(), long_options, 0)) != -1)
{

    switch (val)
    {
        case 'c': clcf = optarg; break;
        case 's': 
            std::cout << "1" << std::endl;

            futures = atoi( optarg ); break;

            std::cout << "2"  << futures <<  std::endl;
            break;
        case 'b': 
            std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
            //blocks = atoi(optarg); 
            break;
        //case 'ss': ssf_spreads = get_value<unsigned>(optarg); break;
        //case 'bs': block_spreads = get_value<stdunsigned>(optarg); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are using non standard stuff, you should mention it. I guess this is the GNU getopt_long from the getopt.h but it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing the arguments? You should pass the arguments without a space, otherwise it will segfault. This has the details: [getopt does not parse optional arguments to parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052746/getopt-does-not-parse-optional-arguments-to-parameters)