# getopt_long() option with optional argument

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to create a option with an optional argument using getopt_long().

Here is my code:

```
static struct option long_options[] = {
   {"help",   no_argument,      NULL, 'h'},
   {"debug",  no_argument,      NULL, 'd'},
   {"config", optional_argument, NULL, 'c'},
   {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

while ((ch = getopt_long(argc, argv, "hdc::", long_options, NULL)) != -1) {
        // check to see if a single character or long option came through
        switch (ch) {
            case 'h':
                opt.help = true;
                break;
            case 'd':
                opt.debug = true;
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("C-Option: %s\n", optarg);
                if (optarg != NULL) {
                    opt.configFile = optarg;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make the argument for `-c` optional so you can run the program with these options:

`-c test.cfg` --> `optarg = "test.cfg"`

`-c` --> `optarg = null`

If I set `c::` than `optarg` is always `null`.

If I set `c:` than I get an error: `option requires an argument -- 'c'`

What did I wrong? Is there any other options I can set?

Comment: Why not define two options: `--opt-1_with-arg` and `-opt-1_use-default`? Or shorter: `--o1a` and `--o1d` or even more shorter: `--o` and `--od` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt):

> If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the option character if present.

Your code works as expected:

```
./a.out -c some_argument --> "C-Option: (null)"
./a.out -csome_argument  --> "C-Option: some_argument"
./a.out -c=some_argument --> "C-Option: =some_argument"
```

You might consider prepending optional argument names with `'='`, as in the above example. Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052746/getopt-does-not-parse-optional-arguments-to-parameters) that discusses the issue.

### UPDATE

I saw a nice solution to this problem in the link to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052746/getopt-does-not-parse-optional-arguments-to-parameters/32575314#32575314) referenced above. The idea is to check, following an option that takes an argument, to see if the next string in `argv[]` is an option. If not, it is assumed to be an argument. The argument is then processed, and `optind` is advanced accordingly. Here is how this idea can be applied to your problem:

```
case 'c':
            if (optarg == NULL && argv[optind] != NULL
                && argv[optind][0] != '-') {            // not an option
                printf("C-Option: %s\n", argv[optind]);
                opt.configFile = argv[optind];
                ++optind;
            } else {  // handle case of argument immediately after option
                printf("C-Option: %s\n", optarg);
                if (optarg != NULL) {
                    opt.configFile = optind;
            }
            break;
```

This code would result in the following output:

```
./a.out -csome_argument  --> "C-Option: some_argument"
./a.out -c some_argument --> "C-Option: some_argument"
```