# Problem with getting arguments from command line

Tags: c++, unistd.h

**strong text**I am trying to get the argguments from this command :

```
./cube -d ../../data/input_small_id -q ../../data/query_small_id -k 5 -M 15 -p 6 -o out
```

And I have a problem getting the k,M and p. To be specific I want k,M and p to be optional_requirements and my program gets only the default numbers I give them. 
All of the numbers are integers(k,M,probes).I have done this:

```
void CubeUtils::getArgs(int argc,char **argv) {

    int c ;
    while (1) {
        static struct option long_options[] =
        {
            //These options don’t set a flag.
            //We distinguish them by their indices. 
            {"d"         , required_argument , 0 , 'd'},
            {"q"        , required_argument , 0 , 'q'},
            {"k"    , optional_argument , 0 , 'k'},
            {"M"           , optional_argument , 0 , 'M'},
            {"probes"           , optional_argument , 0 , 'p'},
            {"o"          , required_argument , 0 , 'o'},
            {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };

        // getopt_long stores the option index here. 
        int option_index = 0;

        c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "d:q:k::M::p::o:a:h",
        long_options, &option_index);

        // Detect the end of the options. 
        if (c == -1)
            break;
        switch (c) {
            case 'd':
                params.input_file.insert(0,optarg);
                break;
            case 'q':
                params.query_file.insert(0,optarg);
                break;
            case 'k':
                if (optarg) {
                    params.K = atoi(optarg);
                }
                else
                    params.K = 3 ;
                break;
            case 'M':
                if (optarg) {
                    params.M = atoi(optarg);
                }
                else
                    params.M = 10 ;
                break;
            case 'p':
                if (optarg) {
                    params.probes = atoi(optarg);
                }
                else
                    params.probes = 2 ;
                break;
            case 'o':
                params.output_file.insert(0,optarg);
                break;
            case '?':
            // getopt_long already printed an error message. 
                break;
            default:
                abort ();
        }
    }
}
```

Params is struct which holds the arguments:

```
struct ParametersCube
{
    string input_file;
    string query_file;
    int K;
    int M;
    int probes ;
    string output_file;
    float radius;

};
```

When its executed I only take the default numbers and never the numbers I give via command line.

Comment: [Runnable testcase](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51fe9073f1c9264d) (please do this yourself next time to save me the time)

Comment: Oh, found a dupe. Leaving my answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be expected behaviour with optional arguments.

Quoting [the `optarg` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optarg):

> *optstring* is a string containing the legitimate option characters. If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg. **Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero.**

…and [the `getopt` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt):

> A simple short option is a '-' followed by a short option character. If the option has a required argument, it may be written directly after the option character or as the next parameter (ie. separated by whitespace on the command line). **If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the option character if present.**

Personally I find that strange, but I can confirm that if you change those arguments to:

```
-k5 -M15 -p6
```

[then it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/699c3b5d87de6a52).

See also:

- [getopt_long() option with optional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40594208/560648)

Comment: Double :: I think are there so you can state that is an optional argument. I don't know for sure, I got the code from gnu and change it a bit so it can fit my case. Can I do something to change that?

Comment: @ΣτεφανοςΠαμποριδης Click on the "see also" (which also the dupe to this Q) for a possible workaround. But otherwise no this is just how it works